How to add additional log statement in Mochaawseome reports in cypress
just logging statement which is inside the it block is executing, but not other, i mean if any logging statements displayed in other methods, if i call that method form it block, those methods are not displaying in the report
No additonal log were displaying in the mochawesome report
